# compileReleaseKotlin fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I'm trying to build my Android Project (which contains a library module) via terminal using gradlew. From within Android Studio, it compiles and installs successfully but, when I try to run `./gradlew assembleDebug` I get the following stacktrace:

```
Using kotlin incremental compilation
e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.JarSearchingUtilKt.findToolsJar(jarSearchingUtil.kt:48)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$toolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:21)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$toolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:15)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment.getToolsJar(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment.getCompilerClasspath(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:24)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.getDaemonConnection(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:289)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:132)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:112)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:49)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinCompilerRunner.runCompiler(KotlinCompilerRunner.kt:134)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompiler(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:73)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:259)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:160)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:141)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor530.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

e: Compiler terminated with internal error
:render-engine:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':render-engine:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

main build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'
    ext.anko_version = '0.9'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '2.3.1'
    ext.appcompat = '25.3.1'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    /**
     *  REQUIRED FOR IGNORING JAVADOCS FOR KT FILES
     */
    tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        excludes = ['**/*.kt']
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }

        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName version

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // TEST
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // GOOGLE
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$appcompat"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$appcompat"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$appcompat"

    // OTHER
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

    // RX ANDROID
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'

    // KOTLIN
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    // ANKO
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

**IMPORTANT: I'm trying that on Elmentary OS (openjdk1.8.0) and the same project can be run on other computer using Ubuntu**

Comment: Why do you have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:...'` twice with different versions of the plugin?

Comment: just a copy paste error, removed one of them but problems pesists

Comment: Restarting the laptop solved this issue for me

Comment: Related question: ['com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context' class can't be found ('tools.jar' is absent in the plugin classpath). Kapt won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759658/e-kapt-com-sun-tools-javac-util-context-class-cant-be-found-tools-jar-i)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, problem is with JDK, I was using Open JDK 8 and it was missing tools.jar for some reason, I switched to Oracle JDK and now it works like a charm!

Comment: openjdk-8-jdk-headless is missing it for some reason. installing openjdk-8-jdk (without the -headless) resolves the issue.

Comment: Switching to non-headless didn't solve it for me; I had to go Oracle

Comment: how to switch into Oracle?

Comment: Same issue for me and same fix worked. Switching to Oracle on Ubuntu: https://medium.com/coderscorner/installing-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-16-10-845507b13343

Answer (score 7):

I solved it only by replacing in build.gradle this

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.30"
```

with this:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have windows, change your PATH so that it includes `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin` instead of `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

Yeah, it might break in an update or whatever, but considering that an update broke my machine... At least you're in control now.

My guess is that `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` points to the non-jdk jre, thus failing to find javac-specific jars.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exact issue on Windows when the JDK bin directory was not in my PATH.

The process is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out that on CentOS 7 this error cab be caused by absence of right java package. So, instead of `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk` I used `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` and it worked. On Ubuntu there is no `devel` packege, but I hope this answer helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath which points to the non-jdk jre, thus failing to find javac-specific jars. Please remove it with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin (for e.g.)