# gradlew assembleRelease Fails With java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

Sidenote - this post is similar (but not identical) to [compileReleaseKotlin fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902679/compilereleasekotlin-fails-with-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-tools?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I thought I'd make my own post with more details about my situation in order to get the best feedback possible. Also, I tried all the solutions in that post, and none of them worked.

I am trying to generate an unsigned release APK for my app. To do that, I use the command `gradlew assembleRelease`.

I get the following error:

```
Caught an exception trying to connect to Kotlin Daemon
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.JarSearchingUtilKt.findToolsJ
ar(jarSearchingUtil.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$t
oolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:20)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$t
oolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:14)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment.g
etToolsJar(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment.g
etCompilerFullClasspath(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:23)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.getDae
monConnection(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:336)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compil
eWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:181)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compil
eWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:156)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compil
eWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinCompilerRunner.runCom
piler(KotlinCompilerRunner.kt:127)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvm
Compiler(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$ko
tlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:378)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$ko
tlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:253)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute
(Tasks.kt:215)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(
Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.inv
oke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:7
3)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskActi
on.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.
execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.
execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.exec
ute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(
DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreating
TaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecute
r.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachin
gStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.
execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTas
kExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExec
uter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStat
eTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsEx
ecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.
execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskEx
ecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecu
ter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFi
ringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.exec
ute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(
DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFi
ringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFi
ringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute
(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute
WithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFai
lures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(Manage
dExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unk
nown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Un
known Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadR
unnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin com
pile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.JarSearchingUtilKt.findToolsJ
ar(jarSearchingUtil.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$t
oolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:20)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$t
oolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:14)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment.g
etToolsJar(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment.g
etCompilerFullClasspath(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:23)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compil
eOutOfProcess(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:303)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compil
eWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:171)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compil
eWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinCompilerRunner.runCom
piler(KotlinCompilerRunner.kt:127)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvm
Compiler(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$ko
tlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:378)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$ko
tlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:253)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute
(Tasks.kt:215)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(
Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.inv
oke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:7
3)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskActi
on.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.
execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.
execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.exec
ute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(
DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecu
ter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreating
TaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecute
r.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachin
gStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.
execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTas
kExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExec
uter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStat
eTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsEx
ecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.
execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskEx
ecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecu
ter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFi
ringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runn
ableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.exec
ute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(
DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFi
ringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFi
ringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute
(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute
WithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExec
utorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFai
lures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(Manage
dExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unk
nown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Un
known Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadR
unnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's some more information about my current situation:

I'm using Windows 10.

This is the result of `gradlew assembleRelease --scan`. It contains a lot of detailed information that could be useful for debugging.

https://scans.gradle.com/s/sohrhovsc676e/

In Android Studio, I went to "File -> Project Structure" and changed my JDK location from

"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre" (embedded JDK)

to

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172" (JDK 8), which I got from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

This failed to solve the problem.

I have also added "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin" to my System Path variable.

I also uploaded my project to Github, incase anyone needs to see it.
https://github.com/vedantroy/recyclerview-test

Also, I previously tried replacing `implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"` with `implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"`, but that didn't work either.

Edit 1 -

I tried switching my Build Variant to "release" and then building an APK and that seemed to work. However, I'm not sure if that produces the same result as `gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Same error here. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this started happening after a Java update. It turns out the JRE was updated but the JDK was not.

Try: install the new JDK update, uninstall old versions, and reopen any shell/ps/cmd sessions/windows. It may be necessary to kill existing Gradle daemons but it should be smart enough not to reuse them. Try your build again!